# Compare dates using comparator in Java

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I would like to compare date times in such a way that I get the end result values that have been sorted in Date ascending and Time descending order. 
How could I achieve this in java using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library?

Data:

```
01/31 5:50
01/31 5:40
01/30 2:20
```

Result

```
01/31 5:40
01/31 5:50
01/30 2:20
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I have tried comparable and I could sort the data with latest Date first only. And what I actually wanted to achieve is to get latest date record combined with the one having the least time, the first record of a particular day followed by the next one in that order.

Comment: We expect to see the code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `TreeSet` (assuming you have distinct dates) using a Comparator comparing the `dateTime.getMillis()` of each date for instance would do the trick.

And better, why not use directly this "out-of-the-box" [Comparator](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeComparator.html) ;)
Up to you to implement the exact logic you want. (ascendant, descendant, whatever)

Answer (score 0):

Write a new comparator and pass it to Arrays.sort() do the work, e.g.

```
    Arrays.sort(Your_JODO_time_array, new Comparator<Date>(){

        @Override
        public int compare(Date o1, Date o2) {
            Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            c1.setTime(o1);
            c1.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
            c1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            c1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            c1.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            Date t1 = c1.getTime();
            c1.setTime(o2);
            c1.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
            c1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            c1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            c1.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            Date t2 = c1.getTime();

            if(t1.compareTo(t2) != 0)
                return t1.compareTo(t2)*-1;
            else{
                c1.setTime(o1);
                c1.set(Calendar.YEAR, 0);
                c1.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
                c1.set(Calendar.DATE, 0);
                t1 = c1.getTime();
                c1.setTime(o2);
                c1.set(Calendar.YEAR, 0);
                c1.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
                c1.set(Calendar.DATE, 0);
                t2 = c1.getTime();
                return t1.compareTo(t2);
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

## Easy in Joda-Time

Sorting is quite easy in Joda-Time. Just a one-liner!

[Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 already implements the `compareTo` method used by the standard Java [Comparable interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). See [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) if you are unfamiliar.

So just add your DateTime instances to an ordered [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) such as [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html), then call the static `sort` method.

The milliseconds since the [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29) of [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) stored within the [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) is used for comparison. So you needn’t worry about time zones.

```java
// Usually better to specify time zone than rely on default.
DateTime now = new DateTime( DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ) );

List<DateTime> list = new ArrayList<DateTime>( 3 );
list.add( now );
list.add( now.plusWeeks( 1 ) );
list.add( now.minusWeeks( 1 ) );

System.out.println( "list: " + list );

// When sorted, the last item moves to first position.
java.util.Collections.sort( list );
System.out.println( "list sorted: " + list );
```

When run…

```
Running 2014-01-31T18:44:34.277-08:00
list: [2014-02-01T03:44:34.390+01:00, 2014-02-08T03:44:34.390+01:00, 2014-01-25T03:44:34.390+01:00]
list sorted: [2014-01-25T03:44:34.390+01:00, 2014-02-01T03:44:34.390+01:00, 2014-02-08T03:44:34.390+01:00]
```